# Suppress Save Dialogue on Before Close Event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button code on a sheet that checks if all the cells in a table have been completed before saving the worksheet. If they're not all complete a userform message box pops up with a reminder then returns to the sheet without saving. I want to be able to call this from the 'BeforeClose' event as well however, even though it still does what it's supposed to do, after the userform message box has displayed and been unloaded then it still pops up the Save Dialog box.

I'm struggling to suppress the Save Dialog box or auto select "Cancel" and return to the sheet for editing

```
Option Explicit

Dim WSh As Worksheet
Dim Create As Boolean
Dim Pipe As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim u As Variant
Dim target As Variant

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Pipe = Sheets("Pipe Cleaning")

Select Case Pipe.Range("N1")

Case Is = False

For Each d In Range("L18:L113")

If d.Value >= 1 And d.Value <= 4 Then
Mbox.Show
Exit Sub
End If

Next d

Case Is = True

For Each u In Range("L18:L113")

If u.Value >= 1 And u.Value <= 3 Then
Mbox.Show
Exit Sub
End If

Next u

End Select





Pipe.Activate
Pipe.Unprotect

Range("A8:A15").EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each c In Range("A8:A15")
Select Case c.Value
Case Is = ""
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Select
Next c

Pipe.Protect

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: They don't seem to suit as they seem to want to save the workbook where as I don't and just want to return to the worksheet and re-edit. Display Alerts is mentioned a lot however this doesn't work for me

Comment: Is the `ActiveWorkbook` a new file? You cannot avoid filename prompt for a new Workbook. Tried `ThisWorkbook.Save`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different issues here.

You need to relocate the code for checking if the sheet is valid for saving into its own function (everything from `Set pipe =` down to `End Select` plus any related variable declarations). If we're OK to save then have that function return `True`; if we're not OK then return `False`

Once that's done the `Click` event procedure can just call that function and examine the return value to decide whether or not to save the workbook

Similarly the `BeforeClose` event procedure could use the function to decide whether we can save or not. If the function returns `False` then you would set the `Cancel` argument of the `BeforeClose` procedure to `True` in order to prevent the workbook from closing

You may need to consider whether the `BeforeSave` event procedure also needs to perform this check

As your program does other work before saving (hiding or unhiding rows) then you probably want to move that into a separate Sub and call that from any event procedure which needs it